# HTTPS RSS URL issue for Feedburner in joomla website

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, joomla, https, rss

I have a Joomla website where RSS feed website structure is like as follows.

http://www.steelmarketupdate.com/blog?format=feed

http://www.steelmarketupdate.com/news?format=feed

Since I have SSL code in `.htaccess` like as follows

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^beta\.steelmarketupdate\.com$ [OR] <br/>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.beta\.steelmarketupdate\.com$ <br/>
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/www\.steelmarketupdate\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

I want to skip above code if URL Query string contains like format=feed
So all feed urls are being skipped for HTTPS.

Any suggestion on `.htaccess` rules ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^format=feed$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?beta\.steelmarketupdate\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.steelmarketupdate.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```